# Verify uniqueness of single value across multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord object that has four `String` columns. I'd like to make a validation that verifies that a certain value is unique across all four columns. For example, assuming the four columns in question are named `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`:

```
FooObject.new( a: 'bar' ).save!
```

should succeed, but

```
FooObject.new( b: 'bar' ).save!
```

should fail because there is already a `FooObject` whose value of either `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d` matches the value entered for `b`. Is there a neat, clean way to accomplish this validation on the object? Thank you!

Comment: @potashin What I'm trying to do is slightly different - that example says the combination of columns shouldn't be unique. What I'm trying to do is make sure a value doesn't simultaneously exist in *any* of the above columns for any two rows. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a custom method:

```
validate :uniqueness_across_columns

def uniqueness_across_columns
  cols = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
  conditions = cols.flat_map{|x| cols.map{|i| arel_table[x].eq(self.try(i)) if self.try(i).present? }}

  !self.class.exists? conditions.compact.reduce(:or)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ["a", "b"]
arr.uniq{|x| x}.size //2
arr << "b"
arr.uniq{|x| x}.size // 2

2 == 2
```

hence this element already exists in the column

`arr` represents a temp copy of one row of `FoObject`